# Конвертация переменных скорости по трем осям и поворота по трем осям в переменную скорости в направлении взгляда

Tags: c++, математика

Ну, есть 6 переменных: velX, velY, velZ; rotX, rotY, rotZ у автомобиля. Их нужно перевести в "скорость в направлении взгляда", что бы я мог определить скорость автомобиля. Но этого мало. Теперь мне эту скорость нужно перевести обратно в исходные переменные, что бы. Что бы я придал машине "скорость в направлении взгляда", она перевелась в исходные переменные, и к машине прибавились исходные переменные описанные выше. Не спрашивайте зачем это, пожалуйста. Если можете, предоставьте код на с++, если нет, сам разберусь.

Comment: Что такое "скорость в направлении взгляда"? Скорость автомобиля вы можете определить без каких-то переводов, она равна корню суммы квадратов скоростей по осям и не зависит от выбора системы координат (если та сама не имеет скорости, конечно)

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%22
я уж подумал меня в гугле забанили, но нет, ваш вопрос найти можно)

Comment: Да, но машина может быть повернута под каким то углом, и в таком случае нужно перевести например число 500 в три скорости что бы она двигалась в сторону куда она повернута. Определить скорость можно, а вот придать то как?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Давайте по порядку. У вас есть сферическая машина. Она находится в вакууме. У неё есть разложенная по трём осям скорость относительно вакуума (velX velY итп) и угол поворота относительно вакуума (видимо возможен дрифт). Далее у вас есть какой-то взгляд, у которого есть направление (скорее всего, это тоже какой-то угол). Этот ваш взгляд - он сейчас с нами в этом вакууме? Если да, знаете ли вы, где он находится и относительно чего смотрит? Т.к. сли он смотрит не отностельно машины, но находится с нами в этом вакууме, то нам понадобятся еще и координаты всех действующих лиц

Comment: Какая сферическая, какой вообще вакуум? Ты о чем? Я вообще говорю про игру NFS:MW. У меня есть все указанные переменные, и указатели на их адреса. Какой ещё дрифт, ты в вообще не о том

Comment: Этот взгляд смотрит относительно лобового стекла в сторону капота

Comment: Ну так что по ответу?

Comment: Стало понятнее, но еще не достаточно. У вас есть два вектора - скорости машины и направления машины (взгляда). Скоростью в направлении взгляда будет скалярное произведение между ними, для его вычисления можно воспользоватся функцией [std::inner_product](https://it.wikireading.ru/36183). Если вектор rotX rotY rotZ единичный, то умножение на него даст вектор скорости в направлении взгляда. Для обратной операции вам нужно сделать соотвественно обратную проекцию вектор скорости точно не единичный, так что нужно еще будет еще поделить на его модуль (тот самый корень суммы квадратов по осям).